# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn stickyHeader - how to add offset e.g. for window insets?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a fullscreen `LazyColumn`:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    item {
        MyHeader()
    }
    stickyHeader {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(32.dp)
        ) { /* ... */ }
    }
    items(20) { /* ... */ }
}
```

The screen sits in an activity with `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` set.

When I scroll, the sticky header will correctly stick, but - as expected - sticks under the statusbar. Is there any way to let the `stickyHeader` element stick with an offset?

[image: sticky header example]

**Edit:**
I want the other content to scroll behind the statusbar. So a `statusBarPadding()` won't work for this case.

Comment: You can add ```Modifier.statusBarPadding()``` in your Root layout ```Modifier``` so it will add Padding on the Top

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that I want the other content to scroll behind the statusbar. So a `statusBarPadding()` won't work for this case.

Comment: make the `Row` background transparent and give it a top padding of `16.dp`

Comment: @rahat sorry, this is not a good solution, because the padding will then also be added, if the sticky header is not all the way scrolled to the top. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @kroegerama The question is, what do you want to display behind the status bar when the header is stuck? Do you want the sticky header's background to show up there? Or you want the other items scrolling behind?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Thanks for your reply! My plan is to fade in a custom StatusBar background in the future. But for now, I just want the other items to scroll behind the StatusBar.

Comment: @kroegerama Do you have only one of these sticky headers in the list or are there multiple ones?

Comment: @kroegerama Also, what do you want to have "behind" the sticky header? So, when you're scrolling the list and the sticky header reaches the status bar's bottom, what should appear as scrolling up behind the sticky header's place in the status bar? The header's extended bottom part, an empty space with the height of the stick header, or the extended top part of the item below it? TL;DR: What is behind the sticky header in your imagination?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy thanks again for your response. I plan to have only one sticky header (will be a tab bar). The background of the sticky header will be just a solid color.

Comment: @kroegerama I mean what would scroll up first _behind_ the sticky header? Something must be _behind_ it because when it gets stuck below the status bar, there's a gap between the header and the items below it (since the gap was occupied by the sticky header). Is that okay to have that gap there?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy oh, I got you. Yes, a gap would be fine. If I get everything working, the plan is fade in a solid color behind the StatusBar. So the gap will not be seen by the user hopefully. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR at the bottom if you just want to see the working example.*

Possibly the easiest way to do this is to "hack" a little with the offset of the sticky header which will push its content down just enough so it won't end up behind the status bar. We need to follow a few steps to calculate the required offset.

First, get the status bar height. `WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(density)` gives us the height in pixels, which is great.

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val statusBarTopPx = WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(density)
```

Then we need to use the lazy list state that you can obtain with `rememberLazyListState()` and set it as the `state` parameter of the `LazyColumn`. This object can be used for getting the layout info of the list items; in our case the sticky header, specifically.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    state = listState,
) { /* ... */ }
```

To calculate the sticky header's offset, we search through the visible list items (`listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo`) when the layout changes, looking for the sticky header. I've done it using the `contentType` of the sticky header but a `key` would also work. When we find the item, we compare it's offset from the top of the list with the status bar height and if it's within range, we calculate the appropriate value that would push down the item enough so it ends up below the status bar.

> Note that this is done in a [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof) so it's only run when the scroll position changes.

```
val stickyOffset by remember(statusBarTopPx) {
    derivedStateOf {
        val offset = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { it.contentType == "sticky" }
            ?.offset

        if (offset == null || offset > statusBarTopPx) {
            0
        } else {
            statusBarTopPx - offset
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have the offset (in pixels) calculated, we will use it in the sticky header. The sticky header is pushed down using the `offset` modifier, which pushes down the `Row` content (*mind that the `offset` is the first modifier, so everything after that is affected by the offset*) with the amount of `stickyOffset`.
Do mind that since the `LazyColumn` places items in a top-to-bottom order, if you push down an item with the `offset` modifier, it will actually be drawn *behind* the next item. This would be the case here with the sticky header as well, however, we can use the `zIndex` modifier to tell the composer that this should draw over other items (that have no z-index set, so they sit at 0 on the Z axis).

```
stickyHeader(
    contentType = "sticky"
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset {
                IntOffset(0, stickyOffset)
            }
            .background(Color.Red)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .zIndex(1f),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(text = "sticky")
    }
}
```

And that is it! Now your sticky header will get stuck below the status bar without it being obscured.

---

**TL;DR**: Full working example:

```
val density = LocalDensity.current
val statusBarTopPx = WindowInsets.statusBars.getTop(density)

val listState = rememberLazyListState()

val stickyOffset by remember(statusBarTopPx) {
    derivedStateOf {
        val offset = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { it.contentType == "sticky" }
            ?.offset

        if (offset == null || offset > statusBarTopPx) {
            0
        } else {
            statusBarTopPx - offset
        }
    }
}

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    state = listState,
) {
    item {
        MyHeader()
    }

    stickyHeader(
        contentType = "sticky"
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(0, stickyOffset)
                }
                .background(Color.Red)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .zIndex(1f),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = "sticky")
        }
    }

    items(20) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(
                    if (it % 2 == 0) {
                        Color.Green
                    } else {
                        Color.Yellow
                    }
                )

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for your detailed answer and all the time you took for this. I really appreciate it! It works perfectly for my use case. :)